# gpu slower than cpu for neural networks in matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, gpu, cpu

I have the following code:

```
tic;
H = rand(100, 1000);
    F = rand(1, 1000);
    net = newff(H, F, [30, 10], { 'tansig' 'tansig'}, 'traingdx', 'learngdm', 'mse');

    net.trainParam.epochs = 400;
    net.performParam.regularization = 0.05;

    net.divideParam.trainRatio = 1;
    net.divideParam.valRatio = 0;
    net.divideParam.testRatio = 0;

    net.trainParam.showWindow = 0;
    net.trainParam.showCommandLine = 0;

    % net = train(net, H, F, 'useGPU', 'yes', 'showResources', 'yes'); % line 1
    net = train(net, H, F, 'showResources', 'yes'); % line 2

toc;
```

with line 2 uncommented I get

```
Computing Resources:
GPU device #1, GeForce 800M

Elapsed time is 5.084222 seconds.
```

and with line 1 uncommented I get

```
Computing Resources:
MEX2

Elapsed time is 1.870803 seconds.
```

Why is GPU slower than CPU?
My GPU properties:

```
CUDADevice with properties:

                  Name: 'GeForce 800M'
                 Index: 1
     ComputeCapability: '2.1'
        SupportsDouble: 1
         DriverVersion: 6
        ToolkitVersion: 5
    MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
      MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152
    MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024 1024 64]
           MaxGridSize: [65535 65535 65535]
             SIMDWidth: 32
           TotalMemory: 2.1475e+09
            FreeMemory: 1.9886e+09
   MultiprocessorCount: 1
          ClockRateKHz: 1475000
           ComputeMode: 'Default'
  GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1
KernelExecutionTimeout: 1
      CanMapHostMemory: 1
       DeviceSupported: 1
        DeviceSelected: 1`
```

Comment: There is always an overhead associated with data conversion and transfer to/from a GPU.  In this case it appears that that overhead is very large in comparison to how fast the algorithm runs on the CPU and hence there is no advantage to using the GPU.  For more time intensive calculations you are more likely to see an advantage with the GPU.

Comment: Thank you. But when I can see the time advantages:
1) In case, where H and F much greater (for example, H = rand(1000, 100000); F = rand(1, 100000)
2) In case, when I train net many times
3) When I increase net.trainParam.epochs = 400000;
What case can give me speed advantages?